# htaccess incorrect redirect, but appears in the browser address bar the correct address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem, I have done several attempts, but the error remains, found it strange because through .htaccess down the page is directed to the correct address, appears in the browser address bar the correct address, but the page is not displayed appears incorrect redirect .

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^central/modules/gateways/boleto/boleto.php(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/central/modules/gateways/boleto/boleto.php$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The url in the browser is displayed right, like this, but no show page, always show incorrect redirect:

```
http://www.domain.com/central/modules/gateways/boleto/boleto.php?invoiceid=1194&cid=20
```

Could help me find the mistake?
Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

redirection entered loop because it was the same old address, I just changed the system folder and changed the .htaccess redirection and work.
The problem is solved!